# Finding the fallacy in this wrong limit computing result

Tags: calculus, limits

for this limit 
$$\lim_{{{k}\to\infty}}{\left(-{\left({2}{k}+{1}\right)}\right)}^{{\frac{{1}}{{{2}{k}+{1}}}}}$$

a friend gives the computing process  like this 
$\lim_{{{k}\to\infty}}{\left(-{\left({2}{k}+{1}\right)}\right)}^{{\frac{{1}}{{{2}{k}+{1}}}}}=\lim_{{{k}\to\infty}}{\left(-{1}\right)}^{{\frac{{1}}{{{2}{k}+{1}}}}}\cdot{\left({2}{k}+{1}\right)}^{{\frac{{1}}{{{2}{k}+{1}}}}}=\lim_{{{k}\to\infty}}{\left(-{1}\right)}\cdot{\left({2}{k}+{1}\right)}^{{\frac{{1}}{{{2}{k}+{1}}}}}=-{1}$

but according to [Mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%28k-%3Eoo%29%28-%282k%2B1%29%29%5E%281%2F%282k%2B1%29%29), the result should be $1$，so what's wrong in the the computing process ?

BTW, my friend also told me Maple gives the result $-1$， is it true ?

Comment: $\lim_{{{k}\to\infty}}{\left(-{\left({2}{k}+{1}\right)}\right)}^{{-\frac{{1}}{{{2}{k}+{1}}}}}$ or $\lim_{{{k}\to\infty}}{\left(-{\left({2}{k}+{1}\right)}\right)}^{{\frac{{1}}{{{2}{k}+{1}}}}}$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen sorry, the first. I updated the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, WA is wrong on this (or doesn't see that $k\to\infty$ is implictily understood by us as something different than $x\to\infty$). For $k\in\mathbb N$, $(-(2k+1))^{\frac1{2k+1}}$is certainly negative, hence there cannot be a positive limit. Extracting $-1$ is fine here.